# Headphone problem

Tags: music, headphones

I have this problem with my headphones. They were working fine up until today, where the music sounds like it's coming from the background and the jack needs to be facing a certain direction and in a specific position to work normally. Anyone know what could be causing it?

Comment: Simply a damaged cord. You need to buy a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more than likely the headphones instead of the phone.

Comment: But as far as what's wrong with the headphones themselves I'd say a short, or something.

Comment: Well they've served me for 3 months now which is somewhat of a record. I'll just buy new ones.